# Sharing templates between subcharts not possible?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to develop some helm libraries for use with own microservices.

The idea is to have development teams being able to quickly wrap their service in a Helm umbrella chart and have as much boilerplate and sane defaults in "common" subcharts that are specified as dependencies.

One subchart (service) defines deployment, service, route and so on - a classic common chart.

A second subchart (platform) contains logic to calculate various things, such as `imageRegistryBase` (we need to pull all images from a image proxy/cache, and prod and test need to use different urls - but all this can be calculated from naming conventions of the kubernetes namespace). This chart is tied closely to the platform (http-proxy configmaps etc). These functions could also be placed in the first subchart, but that would reduce the flexibility of that.

Optimally I could "inject" the platform-subchart into the service-subchart, but don't think thats possible.
Next, I thought that "template names are global" meant that I could simply use the same name for functions in both charts and use that to "override" functions. But it seems Helm does not allow `in subchart A: {{ include something-from-subchart-B .}}`.

Any ideas on how to implement this - or should I just drop it and let the umbrella chart have more hardcoded values :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two charts are in the same release, one chart can call (`include` or `template`) functions `define`d in another.  The thing you describe here that you can't do is to override the base chart's definition of the function; instead, you'll have to pass appropriate parameters into the template function.

If your "platform" chart just consists of a bunch of `define`d functions, then your "service" charts should include it as a normal dependency.  Helm has a concept of a [library chart](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/) that exactly matches this use case.  (In Helm 3 you would include `type: library` in the `Chart.yaml` file, but the pattern existed in Helm 2 also.)  The library chart wouldn't itself include resources, but it could include template functions that produced entire resource YAML specifications; for example, `charts/platform/templates/_deployment.tpl` might contain

```yaml
{{- define "platform.deployment" -}}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
{{ end -}}
```

Your service charts should depend on the platform chart as an [ordinary dependency](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#chart-dependencies).  I'd suggest versioning the library chart the same way you would any other piece of software, treating the set of template functions and their parameters as an API, and then applying normal semantic-versioning rules to the library chart's version.  You might have differently-specialized templates to invoke the library, depending on what exactly these functions produce.

---

I would be hesitant to recommend an umbrella chart, particularly with this setup.  The major problem with an umbrella chart here is that Helm tries hard to flatten all of the dependencies to have a single instance of each.  If you expected each service to have its own in-cluster database, for example, a Helm umbrella chart would only install one database across the entire system.

The library chart in particular has a major lurking problem with the umbrella chart.  Eventually you will need to make a breaking change to the library chart.  When you do, normal SemVer rules would say you should increment the major version.  But now Helm's dependency flattening can't work: if service A depends on library version 1.x, and service B needs library version 2.x, there's no single version of the library that's acceptable.

("All the charts get flattened together" and "charts can call each others' templates" leads to one more possible point of confusion: if two service charts `define` templates with the same name, there will be an unexpected conflict that only emerges in the umbrella.)

Instead, I'd recommend making each service be independently deployable.  Make the Helm charts be self-contained, possibly having a versioned dependency on the library chart.  Either have your CI/CD pipeline run `helm upgrade` for each service, or use a higher-level tool like Helmfile that can manage multiple Helm releases.

Comment: Thank you for your input. 
The platform chart is of type library. The downside of adding platform chart as a dependency to the service chart, is that I can't later use the same service chart with other platforms (charts). 
You say it should be possible for one chart to include a "define" from another chart, but I can't make this work for "sibling subcharts". 
Should add I'm using argocd as well.

Comment: I'd think of chart dependencies like _code_; it sounds like you're saying, in more programmingier terms, that to deploy to a different environment, you link with a different library.  Can you provide these details as Helm values instead (configuration, not code)?

Comment: In programming terms, "dependency injection" would be the solution - the platform functions would be injected into app chart, making it possible to swap out the platform chart with another containing the same interface (defines the same names)